# Replace Unicode characters in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unicode, collation

How do I replace only the last character of the string:

```
select REPLACE('this is the news with a þ', 'þ', '__')
```

The result I'm getting is:

`__is is __e news wi__ a __`

***EDIT***
The collation of the server and the database is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

The actual query I'm running is `REPLACE(note, 'þ', '')` where `note` is an `ntext` column. The point is to strip out the thorn characters because that character gets used later in the process as a column delimiter. (Please don't suggest changing the delimiter, that's just not going to happen given the extent to which it's been used!)

I've tried using the `N` prefix even using the test select statement, here are the results:

[image: Still broken!]

Comment: I have run this query on MS SQL and I got result as `this is the news with a __`

Comment: try select REPLACE(N'this is the news with a þ', 'þ', '__') -- it is not the answer, it is just for comments

Comment: 1) You are not working with Unicode since you are not prefixing any of those strings with a capital `N`. 2) what is your database default Collation? 3) If you run the following, you will get the result you show in the question: `SELECT REPLACE(N'this is the news with a þ', N'þ', N'__');`

Comment: It depends on the collation of your current database - when I try it I get `this is the news with a __`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **þ** character (Extended ASCII { via ISO-8859-1 and ANSI Code Page 1252 } & UNICODE value of 254) is known as "thorn" and in some languages equates directly to **th**:

- Technical info on the character here: http://unicode-table.com/en/00FE/
- Explanation of that character and collations here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation/customization. Search the page — typically `Control-F` — for "Complex Tailoring Examples" and you will see the following:

  > The letter 'þ' (THORN) is normally treated by UCA/root collation as a separate letter that has primary-level sorting after 'z'. However, in Swedish and some other Scandinavian languages, 'þ' and 'Þ' should be treated as just a tertiary-level difference from the letters "th" and "TH" respectively.

If you do not want **þ** to equate to **th**, then force a Binary collation as follows:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(N'this is the news with a þ' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2,
                 N'þ', N'__');
```

Returns:

```
this is the news with a __
```

---

For more info on working with Collations, Unicode, encodings, etc, please visit: [Collations Info](https://collations.info/)

Comment: ASCII doesn't have a codepoint 254 nor the þ character. If you go `SELECT name, collation_name, COLLATIONPROPERTY(collation_name, N'CodePage') FROM master.sys.databases`, I'd be surprise if you see code page 20127 (or 367) listed.

Comment: @TomBlodget Well, yes, _strictly_ speaking, ASCII proper is just 0 - 127. But in practical terms, this character is 254 in [8859-1 Latin1](http://www.ascii.ca/iso8859.1.htm) / [ANSI Code Page 1252](http://www.ascii.ca/cp1252.htm).

Comment: @TomBlodget For some reason I stumbled upon this again after 5 years, and in re-reading it I think I see the point you were making. I think before I was feeling that "ASCII" alone was ok because that's how so many people talk about it, but now I feel that I shouldn't help perpetuate that misuse / oversimplification. So, I updated to clarify that I was meaning Extended ASCII and not standard ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(1000) = N'this is the news with a þ';
DECLARE @find NVARCHAR(1000) = N'þ';
DECLARE @replace NVARCHAR(1000) = N'_';

SELECT REPLACE(CAST(@text AS VARCHAR), CAST(@find AS VARCHAR), CAST(@replace AS VARCHAR));
```

Comment: FYI, you should never use variable-length datatypes without specifying the length. There are two different defaults --1 or 30 -- depending on where it is being used.