# Selecting based on Thorn character MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Consider the following table

[image: Words Table]

created via:

```
CREATE TABLE WORD_TEST(WORD NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO WORD_TEST(WORD) VALUES('these'),('are'),('some'),('test'),('words'),('including'),('puþpies'),('with'),('parents');
```

Notice the Thorn (þ) character in the word puþpies.

Now if I want to do something like find all the rows which have this character in it I would try something like

```
SELECT * FROM WORD_TEST WHERE WORD LIKE '%þ%';
```

Which gives the result

[image]

But the problem is that it also matches any 'th' in the words.
I have also tried the following variations which yield the same result.

```
SELECT * FROM WORD_TEST WHERE WORD LIKE N'%þ%';
SELECT * FROM WORD_TEST WHERE WORD LIKE '%' + NCHAR(254) + '%';
```

How can I select based only on the words that contain that character?

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29013145/2203084

Comment: `SELECT * FROM WORD_TEST WHERE WORD LIKE '%þ%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2;`

Comment: @FelixPamittan Thanks adding the collation does the trick. Apparently I need better search criteria as I never found that answer!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Felix's suggestion to alter the `SELECT` statement would be to set the collation of the `WORD` column when creating the table so that it does not cast the thorn character to something else (apparently `th` in this case):

```
CREATE TABLE WORD_TEST(WORD NVARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2);
```

Now doing your `SELECT` statement should give you the expected results:

```
SELECT * FROM WORD_TEST WHERE WORD LIKE '%þ%';
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes the collation does the trick, unfortunately I can't change the creation of the table, only added it for testing/showing purposes. However adding it to the selection criteria as Felix pointed out does solve the problem.